# Broken action links in timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

[image]

We implemented the action link for our open graph action. Once a story is published to the timeline, we can now see our action link next to Like and Comment. However, clicking on this link doesn't seem to do anything. Looking at the URL, the action_id is '0':

http://www.facebook.com/ajax/open_graph/actionlink?action_ids=%5B0%5D

But if you go to the Facebook activity item page directly (by clicking on the date of the story), you can see the action_id clearly populated. Clicking on the action link at this point works and the story is published to your own timeline.

The action link works as well when it appears in the news feed.

Is there a setting or something we need to do to get the action link working in the Timeline? Or is this a possible Facebook bug?

Comment: Can you please file a bug in the Facebook [Platform Bug Tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)? I've been unable to reproduce it with my own app, so you may have encountered a bug.

Comment: Found that someone is having the same issue: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/422217271145433